# Having a BOF or EOF error, after call recordCount

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have to call `recordCount` function to get the count of recordset.
But once I call `recordCount` function, the recordset is out of control.

```
...
Dim objRootDSE, strDNSDomain, adoCommand, adoConnection
Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
'Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute
Set adoRecordset = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset") 
adoRecordset.cursorType = 3
adoRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient 
adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute
...


totalcnt = adoRecordset.recordCount

If totalcnt > 0 Then 
...
    Do until adoRecordset.EOF
        ' Retrieve values... But it fails because it seems adoRecordset is in EOF
        ...
```

So I use `movefirst` and try to retrieve values.

```
If adoRecordset.recordCount > 0 Then 
                                            adoRecordset.movefirst
    ...
```

But it occurs an error(below is translated by google)

```
ADODB.Recordset 오류 '800a0bcd' 
BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.
```

If I didn't call `recordCount`, there's no problem. But I should know the count of record.

The whole code is :

```
    <%
'On Error Resume next
 Dim objRootDSE, strDNSDomain, adoCommand, adoConnection
 Dim strBase, strFilter, strAttributes, strQuery, adoRecordset
 Dim strDN, strUser, strPassword, objNS, strServer
 Dim name,company,physicalDeliveryOfficeName

 Const ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION = 1
 Const ADS_SERVER_BIND = 0

 ' Specify a server (Domain Controller).
 strServer = "my_ad_server_domain"

 ' Specify or prompt for credentials.
 strUser = "my_account"
 strPassword = "my_passwrd"

 ' Determine DNS domain name. Use server binding and alternate
 ' credentials. The value of strDNSDomain can also be hard coded.
 Set objNS = GetObject("LDAP:")
 Set objRootDSE = objNS.OpenDSObject("LDAP://" & strServer & "/RootDSE", _
      strUser, strPassword, _
      ADS_SERVER_BIND Or ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION)
 strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")

 ' Use ADO to search Active Directory.
 ' Use alternate credentials.
 Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 adoConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
 adoConnection.Properties("User ID") = strUser
 adoConnection.Properties("Password") = strPassword
 adoConnection.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
 adoConnection.Properties("ADSI Flag") = ADS_SERVER_BIND _
      Or ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION
 adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
 Set adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection

 ' Search entire domain. Use server binding.
 strBase = "<LDAP://" & strServer & "/" & strDNSDomain & ">"

 ' Search for all users.
 strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(ExADObjectStatus=10)(samaccountname=*"&"my_search_value"&"*))"

 ' Comma delimited list of attribute values to retrieve.
 strAttributes = "name,company,physicalDeliveryOfficeName"

 ' Construct the LDAP query.
 strQuery = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" _
      & strAttributes & ";subtree"

 ' Run the query.
 adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
 adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 100
 adoCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 60
 adoCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False
 Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute




if not adoRecordset.EOF then 
    totalcnt = adoRecordset.recordCount 
    If totalcnt > 0 Then  
    Response.write 111
        Do until adoRecordset.EOF
            name = adoRecordset.Fields("name").Value
              company = adoRecordset.Fields("company").Value
              physicalDeliveryOfficeName = adoRecordset.Fields("physicalDeliveryOfficeName").Value
              Response.Write name & "<br/>"
              Response.Write company & "<br/>"
              Response.Write physicalDeliveryOfficeName
              adoRecordset.MoveNext
        Loop 
    end if 
end if 



 ' Clean up.
 adoRecordset.Close
 adoConnection.Close 
%>
```

**It shows only one result of record.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to face the problem from a different angle. Instead of trying to fix the internal `recordCount` property (which you can't) simply count the records yourself:

```vbs
totalcnt = 0
Do until adoRecordset.EOF
    totalcnt = totalcnt + 1
    adoRecordset.MoveNext
Loop

If totalcnt>0 Then
    adoRecordset.MoveFirst
    Do until adoRecordset.EOF
        name = adoRecordset.Fields("name").Value
        '...
        adoRecordset.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

**Update**: Looks like in that specific case, the MoveFirst just fails, maybe because it's LDAP and not ordinary query from a database. To bust this once and for all, you can populate your own collection when iterating the records then use that collection as much as you like:

```
Dim oData, oField, tempArray
Set oData = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
totalcnt = 0
For Each oField In adoRecordset.Fields
    oData.Add oField.Name, Array()
Next
Do until adoRecordset.EOF
    For Each oField In adoRecordset.Fields
        tempArray = oData(oField.Name)
        ReDim Preserve tempArray(UBound(tempArray) + 1)
        tempArray(UBound(tempArray)) = oField.Value
        oData(oField.Name) = tempArray
    Next
    totalcnt = totalcnt + 1
    adoRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
adoRecordset.Close

Dim x
If totalcnt>0 Then
    Response.Write("found total of " & totalcnt & " records<br />")
    For x=0 To totalcnt-1
        name = oData("name")(x)
        company = oData("company")(x)
        physicalDeliveryOfficeName = oData("physicalDeliveryOfficeName")(x)
        Response.Write name & "<br/>"
        Response.Write company & "<br/>"
        Response.Write physicalDeliveryOfficeName
    Next
End If
```

Comment: What a smart solution! I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work. `moveFirst` seems doesn't work in my `IIS 6.0`. I think my server has some config problem or sometihng I can't find out.

Comment: What you mean "doesn't work"? What happens when you have the `MoveFirst` line?

Comment: And when you have `Response.Write("count: " & totalcnt & "<br />")` what do you get?

Comment: It shows normal result `count: 13`. I add that code into the loop of `Do until adoRecordset.EOF`, but it didn't come out.

Comment: @Deckard weird. See my edit, this will 99% work though it might be slightly overkill.

Comment: It works greak. And much faster than querying twice :)  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Cheers, glad to find the golden path! :)

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, the recordCount fails if you have no records in the recordset.

You can test for this before your code block. Try this:

```
if not adoRecordset.EOF then
    totalcnt = adoRecordset.recordCount
    If totalcnt > 0 Then 
        ...
        Do while not adoRecordset.EOF
        ...
        Loop
    end if
end if
```

**edit**: Corrected the loop to test for **not** adoRecordset.eof

Comment: It's better, but it shows only one result of recordset. And oricinal code was `do until`. I made a mistake.

Comment: @Deckard Ok, I didn't note that the loop tested on do while adoRecordset.EOF... that should be Do while **not** adoRecordset.EOF (or Do until ..) Btw, do you still need your totalcnt? You could replace the totalcnt with the test on adoRecordset.EOF

Comment: Your recordcount is greater that one ? Do you have a movenext inside your loop ?

Comment: Yes I did. I will add the whole code to my question. Thank you. I just added.

Comment: Code looks ok to me.. I would skip the check on recordCount (and use the check on  adoRecordset.oef instead). Not sure why you only see one row.. perhaps the ldap query already positions you at the last record, than it would make sense to add adoRecordset.movefirst _before_ the Do while loop

Comment: `moveFirst` occurs an error `'800a0bcd'`. I got no way but make two recordsets. I know it's stupid, but I can't help it.. Thanks for your help.